# Unable to run espresso test from android studio with emulator

Tags: android-espresso, android-studio-4.0

I am getting the following error -
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Failed to grant permissions, see logcat for details
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at androidx.test.runner.permission.PermissionRequester.requestPermissions(PermissionRequester.java:111)
at androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule$RequestPermissionStatement.evaluate(GrantPermissionRule.java:133)

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this.

Comment: which Android version did your Emulator ran at? Oreo(8) or P(9.0) and up? I only met this error on emulator running 8.1